# How to use scss functions in Node / Angular / React

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass

I'm writing an Angular project and I'm using SCSS. In particular, I am using the lighten and darken SCSS functions, for example:

```
.my-selector {
  color: darken(#7A9BBA, 15%);
}
```

Now I also need to access this color (and a bunch of other SCSS defined colors) in my controller .ts file. How do you use the SCSS functions in JS/TS code? Is there an npm module for this? TIA

PS I've found this online tool ... http://scg.ar-ch.org ... but I'd like to do it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 days later and I found the answer:

```
npm i --save tinycolor2

tinycolor2('#679467').lighten(5).toString(); // lightens the color by 5%
```

This gives the same result as SCSS:

```
.your-class {
  color: lighten(#679467, 5%);
}
```

Here's my use in an Angular project (and if you are not using Angular it should be easy to adapt):

```
import * as tc from 'tinycolor2'

export const lighten = (color: string, percent: number): string => {
  return tc(color).lighten(percent).toString()
}

export const darken = (color: string, percent: number): string => {
  return tc(color).darken(percent).toString()
}
```

And usage is simple:

```
lighten('#000000', 50)
darken('#FFFFFF', 50)
```

I believe you can also use RGB colors. tinycolor2 has a tonne of other useful color functions to hook into. I am in no way affiliated with tinycolor2.

Comment: this is really useful when you want to animate colors to a lighter of darker (darken) color, such as tweening with npm's popmotion

Comment: you can even tween gradients :)